# Error while accessing Int/Integer element from the List using '!!'

Tags: list, haskell

**Level of Haskell** : Newbie

**Goal** :
       Find the root of an element of the tree represented as a List

**Input (Tree Nodes)  (Positions in Array denote the node number)** :
     [0,1,9,4,9,6,6,7,8,9]

**Function invoked** :
     getRoot 3

**Expected Output** : 
     9

**Code** :

```
li = [0,1,9,4,9,6,6,7,8,9]
getRoot::Integer->Integer
getRoot n | li!!n /= n    = getRoot li!!n
getRoot n | otherwise     = li!!n
```

**Error Message** :

```
ERROR file:.\test2.hs:111 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : li !! n
*** Term           : n
*** Type           : Integer
*** Does not match : Int
```

**Compiler** : WinHugs

Tried various combinations of 'Integers' and 'Int' to declare the type of the function.
It seems that the array access returns an Integer but is then compared to an Int where it fails. Do not know why it does not convert Int to Integers.

Or is it something else all together ?

Searched on the internet, in the tutorials and on stackoverflow.

Comment: A bit of advice: If you're a beginner, don't use `(!!)` or any other index-based function on lists, including `head`, under any circumstances. If you think you need to use those functions, change your algorithm or use a different data structure instead. Continue to avoid these functions until you've learned Haskell well enough to know why I'm giving this advice.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind. Will use recursion and the ':', '++' operators instead.

Comment: @JackBrown Writing your own copy of `(!!)` and using that does not count as not using `(!!)`. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(!!)` has type `[a] -> Int -> a`. If you change the type signature of `getRoot` to `Int -> Int`, the code will compile:

```
li :: [Int]
li = [0,1,9,4,9,6,6,7,8,9]

getRoot::Int->Int
getRoot n | li!!n /= n    = getRoot (li!!n)
getRoot n | otherwise     = li!!n
```

Testing:

```
> getRoot 3
9
```

Comment: ah ! I was not aware that a list type could be declared that way  (li :: [Int]).  This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The type of the indexing function, `(!!)`, is:

```
Prelude> :t (!!)
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

the index must be of type `Int`.

You have a type :

```
getRoot::Integer->Integer
```

where you index, `n` , is an `Integer`. You must convert it to an `Int` to use as an index.

This can be done two ways:

- convert using `fromInteger`
- use [genericIndex](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex)

Also, you should upgrade to GHC and [The Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform), as Hugs is an unmaintained, obsolete version of Haskell.

Comment: Of course, the best way to use `(!!)` is to not use it. Haskell lists are not arrays!

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I will upgrade to GHC.

Comment: @C.A.McCann   Not arrays. Not lists. Whatever. This is a simpler and maybe efficient way to access an element given it's position.

Answer (score 1):

The type of (!!) is

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

In other words, the second argument it accepts should be an `Int`, not an `Integer`. They're different types. If you change your type signature around to accept an `Int` instead, this error will go away.

Also, in order for this to work, your `li` must be a list of `Int`s. You can do this by simply adding a type signature:

```
li :: [Int]
li = [0,1,9,4,9,6,6,7,8,9]
```

With that, all should be well. Good luck!